# Cannot get Application to run on TV

Tags: .net-core, tizen, visual-studio-mac

I am new to Tizen. I got the extension for visual studio mac and Im trying to create a simple hello world program - I want to try the application out on my Samsung tv. I created the solution and the project builds, But it will always fail on installation. I get this generic *installation error* message with nothing else. Did some research around and tried installing the app via the device manager. I get this error every-time.

[image]
I don't know what else to try at this point!

I have also done these things.

- I have installed the TV extensions and certificate.
- I have Created a Samsung Certificate and synced it to my Samsung Account with Public privileges.
- I enabled develop mode on my TV and was able to successfully connect to it via Device Manager
- I clicked *Permit To Install Applications*

Comment: Have you tried using Tizen Studio?link- https://developer.tizen.org/development/tizen-studio/download.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this link:
https://developer.samsung.com/smarttv/develop/getting-started/using-sdk/command-line-interface.html

You can launch your app via CLI instead of SDB Shell.